# How to map domain objects to CQL Tables using Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have two model classes:

```
public class AlertMatchesDTO implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3704734448105124277L;

  @PrimaryKey
  private String alertOid;

  @Column("matches")
  private List<HotelPriceDTO> matches;
...
}

public class HotelPriceDTO implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8751629882750913707L;

  private Long hotelOid;
  private double priceByNight;
  private Date checkIn;
  private Date checkOut;
...
}
```

and I want to persist instances of the first class in a Cassandra column family using Spring Data. In particular using Cassandra template like this:

```
...
cassandraTemplate.insert(dto, writeOptions); 
...
```

and Spring Data have problems serializing `List<HotelPriceDTO>`. What I think I need is a way to tell `cassandraTemplate` how to convert the type. In the official documentation, there is [a chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-chapter) telling that I have to use `CassandraMappingConverter` and `MappingCassandraConverter`, but they do not provide an example yet.

My question is: is there an example of how to register a converter like this (in the test code of the project, may be?) or any other example I can use while the official documentation is completed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hate to say this, but you should RTFM at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/.

Having said that, I noticed the `DTO` suffixes on your class names, which implies to me that you may not have a domain model, only a service layer with DTOs.  If that's the case, you might consider defining the mappings yourself as `RowMapper` implementations and simply use `CqlTemplate` without the bells & whistles of Spring Data Cassandra.  If you choose to fuse the architectural concepts of DTO and entity (entity being a persistent domain object), you're free to use Spring Data Cassandra along with the mapping metadata required (`@Table`, `@PrimaryKeyColumn`, etc).  Your choice.

See http://goo.gl/gPBFpu for more reading on the subject of entities v. DTOs.